# interaction b/w silverlight and javascript for Out of browser applications!

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I did not find any post or tutorial related to the topic mentioned above.

Basically, I am have a page viewed in webbrowser control.

the page is a form . if the form is submitted successfully I get transfer to success page(using HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer)  and if I get transfered to that page , I would like some javascript , Silverlight interaction to let the Silverlight application know that the form is submitted successfully.

thanks

Jamal.

P.S

One way I thought was that, I would check the source of the webbrowser control from the SL app. but source property of webbrowser is not getting updated , if the page gets browsed to some other page from within the page using some hyper link or so.

Answer (score 2):

put following javascript on that page, this will notfiy your WebBrowser control in Silverlight, that the form is submitted successfully, I would suggest using Response.Redirect rathar than Server.Transfer.

> ```
>     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
>         window.external.notify('Your text to pass to Silverlight');
>     </script>
> ```

Register the ScriptNotify event of WebBrowser control in Silverlight..

Xaml:

> ```
>     <WebBrowser x:Name="myWebBrowser" ScriptNotify="myWebBrowser_ScriptNotify" ></WebBrowser>
> ```

Code Behind:

> ```
>     private void myWebBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
>     {
>         string response = e.Value; // e.Value will be "Your text to pass to Silverlight"
>     }
> ```

Comment: hi , i already tried this solution , but i get an javascript error.                                                             an error has occured in script of this page

object doesn't support this property or method.                                                             did your tried this code in Out of browser application ?

Comment: yes, this is working code, and I am using out of browser application. and FYI, the WebBrowser control does not work In browser, it only works in out of browser app.

Comment: hi , I created a sample project and added the code you provided , but the same issue is occuring.please extract the WebBrowserControl.rar file from "http://cid-27fc419fc3a04fa7.office.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public", place the file "webbrowsercontroltestingwebpage.html" in wwwroot folder. open the solution under the folder "LearningWebBrowserSLNavApp".run the project and than in the textbox put the url "http://127.0.0.1/webbrowsercontroltestingwebpage.html"and you will see the error yourself.

Comment: any one who would like to answer this post?